# findstr or grep that autodetects chararacter encoding (UTF-16)

Tags: unicode, windows-xp, windows-vista, utf-16, findstr

I want to do this:

```
 findstr /s /c:some-symbol *
```

or the grep equivalent

```
 grep -R some-symbol *
```

but I need the utility to autodetect files encoded in UTF-16 (and friends) and search them appropriately.  My files even have the byte-ordering mark FFEE in them so I'm not even looking for heroic autodetection.

Any suggestions?

---

I'm referring to Windows Vista and XP.

Comment: Are some of your files in UTF-16 and some in ASCII, or what?

Comment: Yep, some ASCII, some UTF-16.

Answer (score 5):

A workaround is to convert your UTF-16 to ASCII or ANSI

```
TYPE UTF-16.txt > ASCII.txt
```

Then you can use FINDSTR.

```
FINDSTR object ASCII.txt
```

Comment: ...pardon, what?

Comment: or `type UTF-16.txt | findstr` if you don't need filename (OP needs filename because searching multiple files, but some may find this useful)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the suggestions.  I was referring to Windows Vista and XP.

I also discovered this workaround, using free [Sysinternals `strings.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx):

```
C:\> strings -s -b dir_tree_to_search | grep regexp
```

`Strings.exe` extracts all of the strings it finds (from binaries, but works fine with text files too) and prepends each result with a filename and colon, so take that into account in the regexp (or use cut or another step in the pipeline).  The `-s` makes it do a recursive extraction and `-b` just suppresses the banner message.

Ultimately I'm still kind of surprised that the flagship searching utilities Gnu `grep` and `findstr` don't handle Unicode character encodings natively.

Comment: On their home unix environments, UTF-16 is much less common, and files are generally in UTF-8, which they handle just fine.

Comment: Maybe not so great for extracting the whole line, but perfect for trying to find all files containing a string (which I'm trying to do). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you can also use find.exe.

```
find /i /n "YourSearchString" *.*
```

The only problem is this prints file names followed by matches. You may filter them by piping to findstr

```
find /i /n "YourSearchString" *.* | findstr /i "YourSearchString"
```

Comment: Unfortunately find command doesn't support matching patterns like findstr (wildcards / regular expressions).

Answer (score 3):

```
findstr /s /c:some-symbol *
```

can be replaced with the following character encoding aware command:

```
for /r %f in (*) do @find /i /n "some-symbol" "%f"
```

Comment: If add Venkateshwar's answer below, you get:

for /r %f in (*) do @find /i /n "some-symbol" "%f" | findstr /i "some-symbol"

which will filter out the filenames.  I found this useful when searching a set of files looking for "Fail".  I didn't care what file it appeared in, I just wanted to see if any file had "Fail" in it.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [blog article](http://dcortesi.com/2008/07/16/unicode-grep/) by Damon Cortesi grep doesn't work with UTF-16 files, as you found out. However, it presents this work-around:

```
for f in `find . -type f | xargs -I {} file {} | grep UTF-16 | cut -f1 -d\:`
        do iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 $f | grep -iH --label=$f ${GREP_FOR}
done
```

This is obviously for Unix, not sure what the equivalent on Windows would be. The author of that article also provides a shell-script to do the above that you can find on github [here](http://github.com/dacort/ugrep/tree/master).

This only greps files that are UTF-16. You'd also grep your ASCII files the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

In higher versions of Windows, UTF-16 is supported out-of-box. If not, try changing active code page by `chcp` command.

In my case when using `findstr` alone was failing for UTF-16 files, however it worked with `type`:

```
type *.* | findstr /s /c:some-symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which platform you want to do this on.

On Windows, you could use [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com), which automatically detects Unicode files that start with a byte order mark.  (There's also an option to auto-detect files without a BOM.  The auto-detection is very reliable for UTF-8, but limited for UTF-16.)