# How to compile an MQL4 file with a command-line tool?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

Now I am compiling my MetaTrader **`.mq4`** files to **`.ex4`** files with <kbd>MetaEditor</kbd>.

But my `.mq4` files are generated by a Java-process, and I would like to automate the compilation process.

Is there a command-line compiler tool I could call programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an executable in the install directory of the terminal. It is called metalang.exe.

Answer (score 36):

To compile a source code file from a command line, you can use MetaEditor for that. For example:

```
metaeditor.exe /compile:"C:\Program Files\Platform\MQL5\Scripts\myscript.mq5"
```

<sup>For 64-bit use `metaeditor64.exe` instead.</sup>

In Linux/macOS, this can be achieved using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), e.g.:

```
wine metaeditor.exe /compile:"MQL4/Experts/MACD Sample.mq4"
```

For mass compilation, you can specify folder, like:

```
metaeditor.exe" /compile:"MQL5\Scripts"
```

To specify custom MQL5/MQL4 folder with include files, you can use `/inc` parameter, for example:

```
metaeditor.exe /compile:"./Scripts" /inc:"C:\Program Files\TradingPlatform 2\MQL5"
```

For additional information about the compilation process, you can use `/log`:

```
metaeditor.exe /compile:"C:\Program Files\Platform\MQL5\Scripts\myscript.mq5" /log
```

<sup>To check for the syntax only, add extra `/s`.</sup>

If the compilation fails, the `MQL4.log` file would be created in the platform folder with the relevant details. It's going to be in UTF-16 format, so you may need a special tool for it (such as Vim, [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54729247/55075), [`findstr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41840337/55075) or [`rg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236525/55075)).

To specify the custom compilation log file, use `/log:file.log` parameter, e.g.

```
metaeditor.exe /log:errors.log /compile:.
```

Note: [Display to the standard output is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41580912/55075) (although on Linux you can use: `/log:CON`).

For more information, check: [Compilation from the Command Line](http://www.metatrader5.com/en/metaeditor/help/development/compile)

---

Some time ago you could download the compiler of MQL4/MQL5 programs that runs separately from MetaEditor — `MQL.exe`. It was distributed separately from the terminal and you could download it at the following addresses:

> https://download.mql5.com/cdn/web/metaquotes.software.corp/mt5/mql.exe
>
> https://download.mql5.com/cdn/web/metaquotes.software.corp/mt5/mql64.exe

Usage (as per MQL4/MQL5 Compiler build 1162 from 02 Jul 2015):

```
mql.exe [<flags>] filename.mq5
        /mql5     - compile mql5 source
        /mql4     - compile mql4 source
        /s        - syntax check only
        /i:<path> - set working directory
        /o        - use code optimizer
```

However the standalone compiler was intentionally removed, so now links point to the installer in favor of MetaEditor.

---

Much older version of MetaTrader prior to build 600 had `metalang.exe` included with the platform.

However in build 616, MetaQuotes intentionally has removed the compiler (`mql.exe`/`mql64.exe`) from the standard MetaTrader installation.

This means if you upgrade your MT platform (>616), the compiler executable will be removed.

Comment: from wine i didn't manage to get logs or syntax checking! I did manage to compile using "wine" tough which in itself is amazing already!

but if it fails to compile i need to open meta editor and check the error myself.

any ideas?

Comment: @kroe Added extra info. You should check the log file within the platform folder for any compiler errors (`MQL4.log` I believe). Or use the [`mql.exe`](https://github.com/EA31337/FX-MT-VM/releases/download/4.x/mql.exe) CLI compiler and use the mentioned syntax.

Answer (score 5):

This is a little late, but since I wrote a little script for UltraEdit/UEStudio and have received heaps of help from stackoverflow, here is my script. It compiles then copies the ex4 to a number of test MT4 installations:

The "Compile" button on UE does:

```
"MT4Compile.bat" "%FilePath" "%FileName"
Start in path eg: D:\Development\MQ4 (Location of MT4Compile.bat)
```

Normally my source code is in a library tree under D:\Development\MQ4[Group][ExpertName][FileName].mq4

Contents of D:\Development\MQ4\MT4Compile.bat:

```
@echo off
rem Version: 1.1
rem Date:   24 Sep 2013
rem Author: Shawky
rem Refer to HELP: for info

SET XC=xcopy /D /Y /V /F /I
SET PROGDIR=D:\Development\Go Pro Demo (MQ4 Testing)
SET DSTPATH=%PROGDIR%\experts

SET SIMPATH1=G:\Apps\MT4\BackTest IC (Recent)\experts
SET SIMPATH2=G:\Apps\MT4\BackTest IC (All)\experts
SET SIMPATH3=G:\Apps\MT4\BackTest Go (All)\experts
SET DEPLOYPATH=D:\Development\Deployment\experts

SET SRCPATH=%1
SET SRCPATH=%SRCPATH:"=%
IF "%SRCPATH%"=="" (
    SET SRCPATH=[Arg1]
)

SET APPNAME=%2
SET APPNAME=%APPNAME:"=%
IF "%APPNAME%"=="" (
    SET APPNAME=[Arg2]
)

SET SRCFILE=%APPNAME%.mq4
SET DSTFILE=%APPNAME%.ex4


SET CMD="%PROGDIR%\metalang.exe" "%SRCFILE%" "%DSTFILE%"

IF "%SRCPATH%"=="[Arg1]"  GOTO HELP
IF "%APPNAME%"=="[Arg2]"  GOTO HELP

cd %SRCPATH%

IF NOT EXIST "%SRCFILE%"  (
    SET ERROR=Error: File "%SRCFILE%" does not exist in %SRCPATH%
    GOTO HELP
)

echo .
echo Compiling %SRCFILE% to %DSTPATH%\%DSTFILE%
echo .
DEL *.log
%CMD%
IF EXIST "%DSTFILE%" (
    echo .
    echo Distributing executable to SIM and Deployment paths
    %XC% "%DSTFILE%" "%DSTPATH%\"
    IF EXIST "%SIMPATH1%"   %XC% "%DSTFILE%" "%SIMPATH1%\"
    IF EXIST "%SIMPATH2%"   %XC% "%DSTFILE%" "%SIMPATH2%\"
    IF EXIST "%SIMPATH3%"   %XC% "%DSTFILE%" "%SIMPATH3%\"
    IF EXIST "%DEPLOYPATH%" copy /B /Y "%DSTFILE%" "%DEPLOYPATH%\%APPNAME% (Dev).ex4"
)

goto END

:HELP
echo .  Metatrader 4 Command Line utility for compiling MT4 programmes.
echo .
echo .  This batch files allows MT4 applications to be compiled from a directory other than .\experts.
echo .  The output will be copied to experts after compilation.
echo .
echo .  [Arg1] = Path to MT4 application directory
echo .  [Arg2] = Name (without extension) of the main MQ4 source code to compile.
echo .
echo .  Example:
echo .      MT4Compile.bat "D:\Development\MQ4\MyExpert\" "PrimaryMQ4FileName"
echo .
echo .  Programme Directory: %PROGDIR%
echo .  Source Path:         %SRCPATH%
echo .  Source File:         %SRCFILE%
echo .  Destination File:    %DSTFILE%
echo .  Target Path:         %DSTPATH%
echo .
echo .  Argument 1:          %SRCPATH%
echo .  Argument 2:          %APPNAME%
echo .
echo .  Commands to execute would be:
echo .
echo .      %CMD%
echo .      %XC% "%DSTFILE%" "%DSTPATH%\"
echo .
echo .  %ERROR%
echo .

pause

:END
```

All the best.

Shawky