# How to use a logical operator for a preprocessor conditional in an #ifdef compilation directive?

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, conditional-statements, preprocessor-directive, mql4

I've the following code which is using preprocessor [conditional compilation directives](http://docs.mql4.com/basis/preprosessor/conditional_compilation):

```
#define foo
#define bar

#ifdef foo || !bar
  extern bool Verbose = FALSE;
#else
  extern bool Verbose = TRUE;
#endif

void start() {
}
```

which doesn't compile, because of the following error:

> test.mq4(3,12) : error 175: '`||`' - expressions are not allowed on a global scope

However the code compiles fine when the first line (*foo*) is commented out which seems the compiler allows this expression in a global scope in that case (when *foo* is not defined).

You can try compiling above code using [`mql` compilator](http://files.metaquotes.net/metaquotes.software.corp/mt5/mql.exe) (under Linux use `wine`):

```
mql.exe /mql4 test.mq4
```

So the question is:

**Why this doesn't work**
and
**how do I define above preprocessor condition (`foo || !bar`)**
in a proper way?

---

I've also tried the following syntax:

```
#if defined (foo) || defined (!bar)
```

as suggested previously by [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) ([GNU cpp syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html)), but it fails with the following errors:

> error 109: '`#if`' - invalid preprocessor command
>
> error 149: '`#else`' - unexpected token

it's because the MQL syntax is completely different and it doesn't support these kind preprocessor commands.

Comment: What were you trying to do with `#ifdef foo || !bar`? It's not like `foo || !bar` can have a preprocessing definition associated with it. Were you trying to test "foo is defined or bar isn't defined"?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, to avoid repeated unnecessary nested conditions for 4 different possibilities. When the condition is not covered, the compiler complain that it's not defined, if it's defined before, it complains that it's already defined.

Comment: @kenorb it might be worth stating, "***new***"-`MQL4` compiler is `MetaLang.exe` ( which might have troubles with automated LiveUpdate revisions inside **`WINE`** wrapper ) and as such has nothing to do with any part of the **`gcc`** toolchain. So, included documentation rulez. Welcome to the world of `MQL4` moving sands. ( check other posts about this painfull life, if interested to spend a few man*decades in hacking with continuously "*sliding*" `MetaLang.exe` "*new*-**`MQL4`**" syntax rules `:o)` )

Comment: @user3666197 I thought `metalang.exe` (prior to build 600) was the old compiler and it's no longer shipped with platform it-self (as I've explained it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32459182/55075)), so I'm using `mql.exe` and it works perfectly fine under `wine`. If you think it's not the new one, where you can get the latest? I think it's latest, because it says: `02 Jul 2015`. I know it's similar and nothing to do with `gcc`, but previous answer (deleted now) was attempting to answer in terms of it, so I did some additional clarification to avoid any further attempts or confusion.

Comment: @user3666197 I'm also a bit disappointed with the syntax, too much limitations there. You can't actually write any flexible code in it.

Comment: @kenorb Btw, quite interested, what version does your **`WINE`**-ecosystem operate? `2 Jul 2015` sounds like older than actual `MetaEditor.exe; Build 1174; 2015-09-25`. How do you update it? In recent post-new-MQL4 era, whenever you use `[F1]` help, the editor used to inform you ( might got suppresed recently ) about loading a new help file, **which directly warned you**, there is something changed in the syntax. **How do you survive this creeping in `WINE`?** Btw, it is much bigger fun to operate `MQL4` side as a client of a distributed system, where one can enjoy limitless code-execution

Comment: @user3666197 This was the version of the compiler it-self, so I think they're versioned differently and it supports the latest syntax (btw. never used [F1], usually checking on-line docs). The compiler and terminal works under wine-1.6&1.7. Btw. I actually managed to do fully [virtualized backtests](https://github.com/EA31337/FX-MT-VM) under wine, so you can test the terminal in ready-to-use Vagrant VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why this does not work?

**Because**
 
the ***condition*** **syntax does not meet the specifications of MQL4preprocessor**.
<sub>( rather once more 've checked and cross-checked the **`MQL4 Documentation`** 
**Section:
[** `MQL4` Reference / Language Basics / Preprocessor / Conditional Compilation (`#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#else`, `#endif`) **]** )</sub>

---

> Preprocessor conditional compilation directives allow compiling or skipping a part of the program depending on the fulfillment of a certain **condition**.
> That **condition** **`can`** take one of the following forms.
> `#ifdef` **`identifier`**
>       // ... the code located here is compiled
>   
> // ... if **`identifier`** **has** already been defined for the preprocessor in ***#define directive.***
> `#endif`
> `#ifndef` **`identifier`**
>   // ... the code located here is compiled
> // ... if **`identifier`** is **not** currently defined by preprocessor ***#define directive***.
> `#endif`

A **`condition`** is, in this MQL4 preprocessor context, a member of a static, closed set of recognised syntactic directive-constructors **`{`** `#ifdef | #ifndef | #else` **`}`**

An **`identifier`** is, in this MQL4 preprocessor context, a constant `term`, **not** an expression.

**`Q.E.D.`**

---

### A proper way?

One still might opt to construct the missing logic-flexibility "manually":

```
#ifdef bar_identifier
    #ifndef foo_indentifier
         extern bool aCompileTimePresetDefaultToExposedEXTERN_USER_INPUT = True;
    #else
         extern bool aCompileTimePresetDefaultToExposedEXTERN_USER_INPUT = False;
    #endif
#else
         extern bool aCompileTimePresetDefaultToExposedEXTERN_USER_INPUT = False;
#endif
```