# Compiler outputs the errors under Wine, but not on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, compilation, mql

I've got `.mqh` source code file with syntax error, for example created by the following command:

```
echo some_error > fail.mqh
```

Now, I'm using Metaeditor compiler to check the syntax and my goal is to print the errors to the standard output (`CON`), instead of logging them to the file (`/log:file.log`). See: [Compiling](http://www.metatrader5.com/en/metaeditor/help/development/compile).

The following syntax works fine on Linux/macOS as follow (also under `wine cmd.exe`):

```
$ wine metaeditor.exe /s /log:CON /compile:fail.mqh
??fail.mqh : information: Checking 'fail.mqh'
fail.mqh(1,1) : error 116: 'some_error' - declaration without type
fail.mqh(1,1) : error 161: 'some_error' - unexpected end of program
 : information: Result 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

<sup>Please note that the `/log` parameter is required, otherwise the compiler doesn't print anything by default. So if `/log` is specified, then by default it logs the compilation result to the file. And I'm using special `CON` device to display the errors.</sup>

The problem is when I'm running the same command on Windows (cmd), then I've got no output:

```
> metaeditor.exe /s /log:CON /compile:fail.mqh
```

<sup>Same for `CON:`/`con:` as well. Also on *PowerShell*.</sup>

Although `CON` works for `echo`, e.g.: `echo test > CON`.

I could assume it could be a bug of the compiler, but then it works fine under Wine. Why would this work only under Wine?

Is there another way of outputting the errors to the terminal screen on Windows, instead of log file?

---

Note: You can [install compiler from the site](http://www.metatrader5.com/) or download the binary ([32bit](https://github.com/EA31337/FX-MT-VM/releases/download/4.x/metaeditor.exe) or [64bit](https://github.com/EA31337/FX-MT-VM/releases/download/4.x/metaeditor64.exe)) to test above.

---

Clarification: My main blocker for using two separate commands (compile and print the error log after that) is that [CI test](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/kenorb/ci-test/build/1.0.11) may fail before the errors are printed, which makes the tests useless and it's a story for another question. So my goal is to check the syntax and print the errors at one go.

Comment: I'd omit the argument `/log:CON` and eventually add an error output redirection `2>&1'

Comment: However by default the compiler doesn't print anything to the output, unless `/log` is specified, so it logs the compilation result to the file by default.

Comment: Looks like metaeditor behaves/interacts differently in these environments. What about trying `/log:con:`

Comment: Just tested it, same thing.

Comment: Why don't you simply output the log file after the metaeditor command finishes?

Comment: Specifying the filename is the only workaround which I know of (ignoring the fact it's in UTF-16 format, so the system needs to support that as well). Outputting the results to the screen is just more convenient, so I'm looking for some hacks to achieve that. Another downside of two separate commands is that the CI test will fail, before the errors are printed.

Comment: If the output is UTF-16, how does Wine handle it?

Comment: The commands `type` or `more` should display utf-16 (inside font/codepage limits) properly to the screen.

Comment: @MarkRansom Executing under wine it prints `??` at the beginning, but somehow the rest is fine. Printing log via `type` on Win10 is fine. On Linux/macOS, `cat`/`vim` works fine, but `grep`/`less`/`more` and other tools sees it as a binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Support Team, Metaeditor application does not have a console, so it cannot output logs to the screen. So it seems `wine` handles special `CON` device differently. I've reported the issue to the *Service Desk* and it's still open, so they may implement the console support in the future.

Currently the only workaround is to use `type` command for output log file to console after compiling the files (or emulate it under `wine`). Even if the compiler could display it to the console, it won't work properly with CI either (in terms of handling the error codes), because logic of return exit of `metaeditor.exe` is completely broken as it returns the number of successfully compiled files instead of the error code (e.g. if you compile 20 files, you'll get 20 error code?!)! So relying on return exit of `metaeditor.exe` is a mistake and MQL team isn't planning to fix it anyway, since they say this is how it should work in their opinion.