# Compiling MQL4 via command line through wine metaeditor.exe

Tags: ubuntu, wine, mql4

I'm trying to get to a point where I can compile/syntax check via command line so I can avoid using metaeditor for code management.

I'm using this command (also attempted with /s and /log):

```
wine metaeditor.exe /compile:"MQL4/Experts/MACD Sample.mq4"
```

which is from [this MQL4 related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539064/how-to-compile-an-mql-file-with-a-command-line-tool).

I currently get this output and no files generated:

```
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1800f935, 0x640360, {9b18bff9-915e-4cc1-9c3e-f4ac112cb36c}, 1, 0x180b1ba0, (null), (null), 0x640378): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f950,0x00000001,0x33f948) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000280, 00000001): partial stub.
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f4e0,0x00000001,0x33f4d8) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
err:winediag:nulldrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
err:winediag:nulldrv_CreateWindow The explorer process failed to start.
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"gupdate"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000000,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0xa4e734,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids deadbeef: stub
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeEvent stub: 0x14001c1a8 1 1
fixme:ntoskrnl:IoInitializeRemoveLockEx (0x14001c1c0 1297433174 1 100 32) stub
fixme:ntoskrnl:IoAcquireRemoveLockEx (0x14001c1c0, 0x14001bfc0, "", 1, 32): stub
fixme:ntoskrnl:MmGetSystemRoutineAddress L"HalRequestIpi" not found
fixme:ntoskrnl:MmGetSystemRoutineAddress L"HalSendSoftwareInterrupt" not found
fixme:ntoskrnl:MmGetSystemRoutineAddress L"KeIpiGenericCall" not found
fixme:ntoskrnl:MmGetSystemRoutineAddress L"KeInitializeAffinityEx" not found
fixme:ntoskrnl:MmGetSystemRoutineAddress L"KeAddProcessorAffinityEx" not found
fixme:ntoskrnl:MmGetSystemRoutineAddress L"KeGetProcessorIndexFromNumber" not found
fixme:ntoskrnl:MmGetSystemRoutineAddress L"KeQueryInterruptTimePrecise" not found
fixme:ntoskrnl:MmGetSystemRoutineAddress L"KeQuerySystemTimePrecise" not found
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
wine: Call from 0x7f37f3be9f6c to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.__C_specific_handler, aborting
err:seh:setup_exception stack overflow 992 bytes in thread 0036 eip 00007f37f3c1f69a esp 0000000000341220 stack 0x340000-0x342000-0x440000
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
```

For clarity:

- Opening metaeditor.exe through wine and opening a file and compiling
  it works as expected, it's only when I try and execute without
  opening metaeditor it does nothing.
- MetaEditor version: 5.00 build 1562
- Wine version: 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I played around and it seems like something to do with the way the path of the files are passed in.

I modified to use fully-qualified path to metaeditor and a relative unquoted path like this:

```
wine /home/foo/bar/metaeditor.exe /compile:./MQL4/Experts/MACD Sample.mq4
```

Log can only output to a file and requires the path in the same way to work. I simply use a custom IntelliJ filewatcher to monitor my changes and run my compile script, while terminal runs tail -f on my log file.

No more need to use metaeditor, even on Linux!

Answer (score 0):

Wow man, what a struggle!
The same thing happened to me. The EA would compile (but not work!) with the wine command line compile. But, compile (and work) when I used the metaeditor.exe gui

Long story short, eventually got it with this command

```
/usr/bin/wine /path/to/MT4/metaeditor.exe /compile:"Z:\path\to\MT4\MQL4\Experts\Foo\Bar_EA.mq4" /include:"Z:\path\to\MT4\MQL4" /log
```

Phew!