# VSCode Linux tasks.json MQL4 Compilation

Tags: json, linux, visual-studio-code, mql4, wine

I am switching to VSCode from MetaEditor to develop for MetaTrader4.

I'm using MetaTrader4 and MetaEditor in Linux via Wine.
(and MetaEditor runs quite terribly in Wine)

I would like to create a task to compile the code, and hopefully return the same error log to VSCode to further debug the code as if I was using MetaEditor.

I've used this post to figure out what CLI command has been used to compile MQL4:
[Compiling MQL4 via command line through wine metaeditor.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494080/compiling-mql4-via-command-line-through-wine-metaeditor-exe)

```
/usr/bin/wine /path/to/MT4/metaeditor.exe /compile:"Z:\path\to\MT4\MQL4\Experts\Foo\Bar_EA.mq4" /include:"Z:\path\to\MT4\MQL4" /log
```

My issue is that I don't understand and cannot find any resource that explains what the "commands" inside the tasks.json file does or list of available variables.  Like "/include:" or "presentation":, ${file}, etc.

So I took some guesses and I pieced it together to look something like this so far:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "MQL4 Compile",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/usr/bin/wine /.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/FXChoice MetaTrader 4/metaeditor.exe",
            "args": [
                "/compile:${file}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Its probably not quite right.
I appreciate your help, thank you

Answer (score 3):

```mql
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": 
  [
    {
      "label": "MQL4-Compile",
      "group": 
      {
        "kind"      : "build",
        "isDefault" : true
      },
      "presentation": 
      {
        "echo"  : true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus" : true,
        "panel" : "shared"
      },
      "promptOnClose" : true,
      "type"          : "process",
      "osx"           : 
      { 
        "command" : "wine",
        "args"    : 
        [ 
          "/Users/SVG/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/MetaTrader/metaeditor.exe",
          "/compile:${fileBasename}",
          "/log:${fileBasenameNoExtension}.log",
        ]
      },
      "windows"   : 
      { 
        "command" : "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MetaTrader\\metaeditor.exe",
        "args"    : 
        [ 
          "/compile:${fileBasename}",
          "/log:${fileBasenameNoExtension}.log",
        ]
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: fix the way yourself