# findstr won't give the correct errorlevel

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I've tried almost everything but I can't get the `findstr` command to work. The code below keeps giving me `mbam scannen`.

```dos
@Echo OFF

Set "log_file=T:\Scholen\RC01\Hitman\Hitman_RC01TS001-201304061026.txt"

findstr /C:"Malware _" T:\Scholen\RC01\Hitman\Hitman_RC01TS001-201304061026.txt

If errorlevel 1 (
    Echo Mbam scannen
    Pause
) else (
    Echo Mbam stoppen
    Pause
)
```

Can someone please guide me to a solution?

Comment: Please show the content of the `Hitman_RC01TS001-201304061026.txt` and the output of the command `dir /a-d/b "T:\Scholen\RC01\Hitman"`.

Comment: The dir command shows

T:\>dir /a-d/b "\Scholen\RC01\Hitman"
Hitman_
Hitman_RC01TS001-201304061026.txt
  
The file contains:
   Remnants scanned  . . : 260,994 files / 1,377,513 keys

Cookies _____________________________________________________________________

Malware _____________________________________________________________________

   C:\Users\administrator.AD\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies:ad.360yield.com

But when I remove the Malware ___ line the errorlevel won't change

Comment: Sorry for the markup of above comment, I'm new to stackoverflow commenting...

Comment: I can't see any code in the comment box. Please edit your answer or put it at `pastebin.com`.

Comment: I've made the whole post on pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/emaaCb15)

Comment: It does work for me [here](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/hpejh5ix/snap125.gif).

Comment: The output in your screenshot should be "mbam scannen" because "Malware _" is found in the textfile. Your screenshot shows "Mbam stoppen"

Comment: Yes, but `findstr` is true. Also, if it finds `"Malware _"`, the errorlevel is `0`, **not** `1` --> also `stoppen`. And in your `Hitman_RC01TS001-201304061026.txt` is the pattern `"Malware _"`. OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a problem with the encoding of the file. Open the text file in Notepad, click *File → Save As...*, and check the *Encoding* field at the bottom center of the *Save As* dialog. If the field doesn't say `ANSI`, then the file is Unicode-encoded, which prevents `findstr` from finding a match.

Try using `find` instead, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14244839/1630171):

```
find /c "Malware _" T:\Scholen\RC01\Hitman\Hitman_RC01TS001-201304061026.txt >nul
```

Comment: I now have [this](http://pastebin.com/fMvekWZU) and it works, so this is better I guess?

Comment: If it works, it works :) `find` can read Unicode, `findstr` not, this is Microsoft.

Comment: [MS explained why they have both find and findstr, and furthermore, why the two programs have unrelated features. The `find` program supports UTF-16, which `findstr` doesn't; on the other hand, the findstr program supports regular expressions, which find does not.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121128-00/?p=5963)