# Find files that contains error code 500 from list of XML files using command in Windows

Tags: windows, file, iis, cmd, error-handling

I want to find the IIS and web application error code 500 (or 500 Series) from the list of XML files in a directory.

I'm using command prompt (with command `findstr`) to go through list of XML files in that directory. However, unable to find any. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I'm not sure which particular command to use for this particular XML files.

The command I am using is: `findstr /s /i HttpStatus 500 *.*`

What is the exact command parameters I should give to find error code 500 from these list of XML files? Or is there any other possible ways to get this?

Comment: The files are [in UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/408079/11683), aren't they?

Comment: `findstr /s /i /r /c:"HttpStatus *500" *.xml` or 500 series `findstr /s /i /r /c:"HttpStatus *5[0-9][0-9]" *.xml`

Comment: These are .XML files having data like this : <Data Name=“HttpStatus”>500</Data> These are logs not sure about UTF-16.

Comment: @penknife Thanks for the clue. However, it’s not working. Is this tried with the XML format I have provided? Any other ways??

Comment: @GSerg Looks like by default the files are in UTF-8, when opened in notepad++